# Ubuntu Firewall: How to drop all TCP reply packets from an IP address

Tags: networking, ubuntu, firewall

I've got two Ubuntu boxes, A and B.

A is starting a TCP connection to B.

I want A's TCP SYN packet to arrive at B, but when B's SYN/ACK reply packet comes back to A, I want A's firewall to drop it.

What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Just curious, why would you want this? Academic purposes?

Comment: Yeah, it's not a firewall rule I'd want to use on a real system. I'm trying to reproduce a network problem that we encountered with a faulty router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following iptables rule will drop ACK's from host A:

> iptables -A INPUT -s ip.of.host.a/32 --protocol tcp --tcp-flags ACK ACK -j DROP

`--tcp-flags` is documented in the man page for [iptables-extensions](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html):

> [!] --tcp-flags mask comp
>       Match when the TCP flags are as specified. The first argument mask is the flags which we should examine, written as a comma-separated
>   list, and the second argument comp is a comma-separated list of flags
>   which must be set. Flags are: SYN ACK FIN RST URG PSH ALL NONE. Hence
>   the command
>
> ```
>  iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK,FIN,RST SYN
>
> will only match packets with the SYN flag set, and the ACK, FIN and RST flags unset.
> ```

Comment: Ah, my thanks.  I think it needs to be --tcp-flags ACK ACK.  Otherwise, I get a "iptables v1.4.21--tcp-flags requires two args" error.   Strangely the man pages for iptables doesn't mention --tcp-flags at all.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer. Also found where `--tcp-flags` is documented for your reference :)